# Olympiad Geometry Question on Tangents and Collinear Circles

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

I'd like help on the following problem:

There are three circles $A,B,O$ in the plane. The radius of $A$ is $12$, the radius of $B$ is $8$ and they are both inside of $O$. The centre of $O$ is the midpoint of the centres of $A$ and $B$. If $p,q$ ($p>q$) are the lengths of the lines which are tangent to $A$ and $B$, as shown in the diagram, then what is the value of $p^2 - q^2$?

I know the answer is $384$, but I can't seem to find why.

[image]

Comment: Do we know anything about the radius of $O$?

Comment: There's no information on the radius of O

Comment: If $r$ is the radius of the largest circle, we have $\space\dfrac{p}{2}=\sqrt{r^2-\left(\dfrac{12+8}{2}\right) ^2}\space$ and $\space\dfrac{q}{2}=\sqrt{r^2-\left(\dfrac{12-8}{2}\right) ^2}$. Using this pair of equations, you can estimate $p^2-q^2$.

Comment: we aren't given any information about the radius of the largest circle O :///

Comment: We don't need it. $r$ cancels out when you determine $p^2-q^2$.

Comment: OHHHHH okay, i see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following diagram:

[image]

The right triangle with the red dashed hypotenuse of length $r_O$ and the dashed leg containing the center of circle $O$, has solid leg
$$
\frac p2=\sqrt{r_O^2-\left(\frac{r_A-r_B}2\right)^2}\tag1
$$
The right triangle with the green dashed hypotenuse of length $r_O$ and the dashed leg containing the center of circle $O$, has solid leg
$$
\frac q2=\sqrt{r_O^2-\left(\frac{r_A+r_B}2\right)^2}\tag2
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
p^2-q^2
&=(r_A+r_B)^2-(r_A-r_B)^2\tag{3a}\\
&=4r_Ar_B\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$